# Regex to allow the same word but 32 random characters

Tags: regex

This seems so simple but my brain just can't put it all together.
I have an end of the URL string which is formatted like this:

CORE65D5B779E35D4F4ABDE327B81725B854

It always starts with CORE and has 32 random characters after.

CORE04F45C975E7D493097634C8AC638D4F9

CORE248C7E54425244D98D7A1CE5587E0E76

CORE65D5B779E35D4F4ABDE327B81725B854

I want to validate to make sure the user inputs this correctly but I can't figure out to do it.
So if they add more characters, omit CORE, or paste the entire URL it will error, I just want the above string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the language you want to have the regex in. For Java you can use `CORE[A-Z0-9]{32}`. Feel free to play with tools like https://regex101.com/ to check how it would look like for other languages.

Comment: Thank you. The site I am using just says Regular Expression so not 100%.
I also tried your solution, but the site keeps converting it to:
^CORE[A-Z0-9]{32}$

So when I type CORE222 it accepts it still. Even if I type /////fokgoCORE it also accepts it.

Comment: `^` is to mark the start of the string and `$` the end. Depending on the regex engine or programming language, this is important, because without it, the program could match substrings and not the whole input.

Comment: Please clarify, @Darkstar.Industries, as `^CORE[A-Z0-9]{32}$` will not accept `CORE222`.